# Expected value of product measure?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

Given two real valued random variables $X$ and $Y$ on $(\Omega, \Sigma)$, we can define a random variable $Z=(X,Y)$ on $(\Omega \times \Omega, \Sigma \otimes \Sigma)$. But what is the expected value of $Z$ then?

I mean we can still use the "normal" definition of the expected value, but the expected value would be in $\mathbb R^2$, not in $\mathbb R$. Is that okay? And if so, how do terms like "uncorrelated" translate? Do we want $E(Z_1 Z_2)-E(Z_1)E(Z_2)= (0,0)$ then?

Comment: Yes, it is in $\mathbb{R}^2.$ As for your second question, we would use matrices as is explained in [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_random_variable).

Comment: Get familiar with [random vectors](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_random_variable).

Comment: Note that the measure(joint distribution)  induced by $Z$ on $\Bbb{R}^{2}$ NEED NOT be the product measure of the two distributions $\mu_{X}$ and $\mu_{Y}$. If it is indeed the product measure, then we say that $X$ and $Y$ are independent variates (and vice versa, i.e. independent variates induce the product measure)  And being uncorrelated is not a property of being independent or not. There are variates $X$ and $Y$ which don't induce the product measure(hence not independent) but are uncorrelated. Being uncorrelated just means that covariance is $0$. That's it

Comment: Secondly, $Z$ has no "expected" value. $Z$ is just a random vector. It is not a real valued quantity but rather a $\Bbb{R}^{2}$ valued quantity. However, one can talk about functionals of $f$ and their expected value. i.e. if $f:\Bbb{R}^{2}\to \Bbb{R}$ is a measurable function, then we can talk about $E(f(Z))$. Additionally, there is something called the mean vector which is just $(E(X),E(Y))$ which is just a column matrix containing the means and is sometimes useful to write things in matrix notation. Otherwise, it has no other significance than something which tells you what means each have.